# WKHTMLTOPDF breaks saying --margin-bottom invalid argument

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

My application generates a PDF file from a webpage using WKHTMLTOPDF tool. Application written with Symfony2 framework and I am using a **Symfony2** [process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) to run the shell command to call WKHTMLTOPDF. My command is like below.

```
C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --margin-bottom '0' --margin-left '0' --margin-right '0' --margin-top '0' SOURCE.html SOURCE.pdf
```

This gives me an error now.

*Invalid argument(s) parsed to --margin-bottom*

is the error I am getting. I am really confused because for some cases it is working perfectly. Only some cases it is not working.

When I try to run the same command in the CMD, it works. Only symfony process gives error.

I really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I am using Wkhtmltopdf  version 0.12.1-9615f00. And symfony version is 2.7

Comment: Can you try pass these instead of --margin-x ect. `-L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -B 0`